# Export Multiple Tables Data With Toad Oracle

Tags: oracle, export-to-csv, toad

I need to automate the export of data from 37 tables out of Oracle using Toad (preferably).  Is anyone familiar with scripting this out in Toad or Oracle SQL Developer so that it can be automated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't use a host script?

Comment: define what you mean by 'export - simple ddl/sql insert statements? or something that scales for very large tables (data pump)?

Comment: [Also see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54788833/how-to-export-data-from-around-300-tables-in-oracle-db-to-csv-or-txt-files)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the answer.  Below is what I needed to do, and I can also schedule the exports.

1. Go to automation designer.
2. Drop in an “Export dataset” action.
3. Double-click the new action and set whatever export options you want.
4. On the “Dataset” tab, enter your query. Click “Apply” and then close the dialog.